# Python equivalent of Ruby `if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME`

Tags: python, ruby

In Ruby, you can write a class/module such that it can be (a) loaded into an interactive Ruby terminal without actually executing code, or (b) run as a shell script.

For example, given file `foo.rb`:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts 'Foo bar'
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  foo = Foo.new
  foo.bar
end
```

This would load the `Foo` class for use in `irb` or `pry`, but wouldn't execute the instantiation of `foo` or the method call `foo.bar` inside the `if` statement at the end.

But if run in the command line with `ruby foo.bar` it would return `"Foo bar"` and exit.

**Is there a Python (v2 or v3) equivalent of this?**

The closest I've come (in 2.7) is this, but I feel like there might be a cleaner way:

```
import os, sys

if os.__file__ == sys.argv[0]:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Are you talking about: `if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
`

Comment: But `__name__ == "__main__"` is true regardless of whether you're in an interactive shell, isn't it?

Comment: if you want to create a file which can be run independently as well as defining scripts adding that would allow you to have a default main if the file is run standalone.  If the file is run as an imported item, it wouldn't run the main, but instead just define in your case, the class `Foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, when you are running a file independantly vs a part of a module, you can do something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

which will run `main()` if the python file is executed independently.

In your example, you would likely want something like this.

```
class Foo:
  def bar(self):
    print 'Foo bar'

def main():
  foo = Foo()
  foo.bar()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I personally like to define a main function as the above example, but could easily just do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
  foo = Foo()
  foo.bar()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python modules include a `__name__` variable holding the module name. If its the top level script, the name is `__main__`.

```
class Foo:
  def bar(self):
    print('Foo bar')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  foo = Foo()
  foo.bar()
```